# Jenkins windows slave git credentials for nt authority\system storage location

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, puppet

I am using a windows slave to clone a git repo and run jenkins build jobs. I'd like to clone without supplying credentials each time so I plan to use a _netrc file with the standard settings. When I run 'whoami' in the job I get the following:

```
nt authority\system
```

My question is - where does this user have their credentials stored? Is it possible to use a _netrc file for authentication for this user like I would with my own user account?

Comment: One workaround is to use the "Run service as" option and select "Log on using a different account" and then input the same credentials.